# When doing an update to the data and labels the chart is not able to add more columns

Tags: javascript, chart.js

So my inherent chart setup is

```
var chart2config = {
    type: "bar",
    plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
    data: {
    //labels:['hello','goodbye','hello','goodbye','hello','goodbye','hello','goodbye','hello','goodbye','hello'],
    labels:[],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Summer Semester',
        pointRadius: 4,
        pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,255,1)",
        data: [500,1000],
        stack: "number1"
      }]
    },
    options:{
        responsive: true,
        scales: {
            x: {
                stacked: false
            },
            y: {
                stacked: true
            }
        },
        plugins: {
            datalabels: {
                color:'red',
                rotation:90,
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                anchor:'end',
                labels: {
                    title: {
                      font: {
                        weight: 'bold',
                        color:'red'
                      }
                    }
                },
              font: {
                weight: 'bold'
              }
            }
    }
    }
  };
```

I then run

```
 axios.post('/allyears_semester_archive', {
})
.then(function (response) {
  chart2data = response.data;
  console.log(response.data);
  console.log(chart2data.years);

  chart2config.labels = chart2data.years;
  chart2config.data.datasets[0].data = chart2data.summer;
  var chart2 = new Chart(ctx_archive_live,chart2config);

})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);

});
```

> chartdata2.summer and chartdata2.labels are arrays as confirmed in the console.

When the chart is redrawn I get

[image]

If I were to start with

> labels:['hello','goodbye','hello','goodbye','hello','goodbye','hello','goodbye','hello','goodbye','hello']

I would get the below where the data fits for the update but the labels are of course no updated again... not sure how to do this so that the chart updates correctly.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get how you redraw the chart. Are you refreshing the page or are you clicking some interface element?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to take a look at https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html to see how to update Chart.js data and labels.

Taking a look at the your code snippet, which updates the chart here:

### Your code snippet to be changed

```js
chart2data = response.data;
console.log(response.data);
console.log(chart2data.years);

chart2config.labels = chart2data.years;
chart2config.data.datasets[0].data = chart2data.summer;
var chart2 = new Chart(ctx_archive_live,chart2config);
```

### Updating an existing chart

If possible, update an existing chart instance. I changed your snippet accordingly, where `chartObj` is your Chart instance:

```js
chartObj.data.labels = response.data.year;
chartObj.data.datasets[0].data = response.data.summer;

chartObj.update();
```

Double check, that your `response.data` is in the correct form and that you actually have access to the `chart2config` object where you are updating. Then following the Chart.js docs about updating, as I tried above with limited knowledge about your data, should work.

### Instantiating a new chart

In case you do not want to update an existing chart, but do want to create a new one, I think the problem with your code snippet might be that you have to assign the labels to the data property inside the config object. Try this instead:

```js
chart2config.data.labels = response.data.years;
chart2config.data.datasets[0].data = response.data.summer;
var chart2 = new Chart(ctx_archive_live, chart2config);
```

Comment: Chart2config is just the chart configuration..has nothing to do with create a chart instance....from the documentation you set the config stuff and then update the chart instance to I don't follow what you are getting at...

Comment: True, I missed that in your first snippet. You were talking about "updating" a chart, so I was assuming there must be already an existing instance present. I changed my answer accordingly, covering both cases (updating/instantiating). I also found another possible problem. Notice how I used `chart2config.data.labels` instead of `chart2config.labels`? That might be the problem.